# Java Mail Slow downloading attachment Office 365

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am reading the inbox of an office 365 Mail account and downloading the attachment of it (txt files). It works fine with small files less than 2 MB but when I tried with a 20 MB file, It is really slow. I test the code in two different machines (Linux and Windows) and the speed was the same, really slow.

```
String user = "mail@mail.com";
String password = "mypassword";
try{

    boolean foundSites = false;

    // Get a Properties object
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put("mail.imaps.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.imaps.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", SSL);
    //properties.put("mail.imap.fetchsize", "1000000");
    Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
    Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect(host, user, password);

    //create the folder object and open it
    Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
    Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
    System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    int year = now.getYear();
    int month = now.getMonthValue();
    int day = now.getDayOfMonth();

    for (int i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Message message = messages[i];


    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(message.getReceivedDate());
    int yearMessage = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int monthMessage = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int dayMessage = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



    if(year == yearMessage && month == monthMessage && day == dayMessage)
    {
        //The real code is doing this with 20 Subjects (20 emails)
        if(message.getSubject().equalsIgnoreCase("Integration - Site Info") && foundSites != true)
        {
            System.out.println("found Integration - Site Info");

            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            List<File> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < multipart.getCount(); j++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(j);
                if(Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition()))
                {
                    InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();
                    File f = new File("./attachments/"
                            + "sites_"+Integer.toString(day)+"-"+Integer.toString(month)+"-"+Integer.toString(year)+".csv");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while((bytesRead = is.read(buf))!=-1) {
                        fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    fos.close();
                    attachments.add(f);
                    foundSites = true;
                    break;
                }


            }
        }
    }

    if(foundSites)
    {
        break;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);  
}
```

I can possibly create threads, but is there any other alternative?

Just a side note:
I try the code with python and the speed improve significantly.

======================================
UPDATE 1:

I did the change to saveFile method and the code simplifies a lot, but still the same downloading speed of 10 KB per second.

```
MimeBodyPart bodyPart = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(j);
if(Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition()))
{
    bodyPart.saveFile("./attachments/"
        + "sites_"+Integer.toString(day)+"-"+Integer.toString(month)+"-"+Integer.toString(year)+".csv");
```

I also use the profiler and the results are:
[image]

[image]

Comment: How slow is really slow? How fast is fast enough?

Comment: Have you profiled the code? Run it with jvisualvm, and tell us which part is slow. Off the top of my head, you *might* add buffering to the `FileOutputStream`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Simplify your code by using [MimeBodyPart.saveFile](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#saveFile-java.lang.String-) to save the attachment.

Since you're using the "imaps" protocol and not the "imap" protocol, set the `mail.imaps.fetchsize` property to something large enough to get the performance you want without using more memory than you want to use.  Or set `mail.imaps.partialfetch` to false if you don't care how much memory you use and you're sure you'll always have enough.

Comment: I did the saveFile Method, it really simplifies the code but the download speed still in 10 KB per second.

Comment: Why don't you try the other changes I suggested?

Comment: I set the `mail.imaps.partialfetch` property to false and the `mail.imaps.fetchsize` to 2000000

Now the speed really improve! thanks! Do you have some recommendations on how to optimal calculate this values?.

Comment: Experimentation.  It's a tradeoff between speed and memory.